# On a general system of linear equations in a derivative problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials, systems-of-equations

For some days a problem that I encountered in the Calculus textbook of mine has been preying upon my mind. The problem is as follows:

*Determine the expression for the polynomial $F(x)$ given that it satisfies the following relation: $$ c_0 F(x) + c_1 F’(x) + c_2 F’’(x) = P(x),$$ where $$P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^n, \,\,\, c_0,c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$$*

The first observation I made was blindingly obvious: $F(x)$ must also be a polynomial of degree $n$ (for taking any derivative of a polynomial reduces its degree; and if $p(x),q(x)$ are polynomials, then any linear combination of them with non-zero coefficients possesses the degree $\max\{\deg{p};\deg{q}\}$). For that matter, I put $$F(x) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 x^2 + \ldots + \alpha_n x^n.$$ Having taken the derivatives of $F(x)$, plugged them into the equation from the formulation of the problem, and equated the coefficients, I arrived at the following system of equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\alpha_0 c_0 + \alpha_1 c_1 + 1\cdot2 \alpha_2 c_2 &= a_0\\
\alpha_1 c_0 + 2\alpha_2 c_1 + 2\cdot3 \alpha_3 c_2 &= a_1\\
\alpha_2 c_0 + 3\alpha_3 c_1 + 3\cdot4 \alpha_4 c_2 &= a_2\\
\alpha_3 c_0 + 4\alpha_4 c_1 + 4\cdot5 \alpha_5 c_2 &= a_3\\
\dots\\
\alpha_{n-2} c_0 + (n-1)\alpha_{n-1} c_1 + n(n-1) \alpha_n c_2 &= a_{n-2}\\
\alpha_{n-1} c_0 + n\alpha_n c_1 &= a_{n-1}\\
\alpha_n c_0 &= a_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

After that, I decided to divide each equation by $c_0$, and, putting $$C_1 = \frac{c_1}{c_0}; \,\, C_2 = \frac{c_2}{c_0}; \,\, A_i = \frac{a_i}{c_0},$$ I ended up with the following:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 C_1 + 1\cdot2 \alpha_2 C_2 &= A_0\\
\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 C_1 + 2\cdot3 \alpha_3 C_2 &= A_1\\
\alpha_2 + 3\alpha_3 C_1 + 3\cdot4 \alpha_4 C_2 &= A_2\\
\alpha_3 + 4\alpha_4 C_1 + 4\cdot5 \alpha_5 C_2 &= A_3\\
\dots\\
\alpha_{n-2} + (n-1)\alpha_{n-1} C_1 + n(n-1) \alpha_n C_2 &= A_{n-2}\\
\alpha_{n-1} + n\alpha_n C_1 &= A_{n-1}\\
\alpha_n &= A_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I have not yet been able to derive the general expression for $\alpha_i$. I have already tried expressing a few alphas from the end (i.e. beginning with $\alpha_n$) for a possibility of spotting a pattern, but so far the only meaningful result I have been able to extract from all this is $$\alpha_i = \sum^{n-i}_{j=0} (-1)^j Q^{i+j}_{i} p_j A_{i+j},$$ where $$Q^{n}_{k} = \frac{n!}{k!},$$ and $p_k$ is are polynomials in $C_{1,2}$, which, as far as I am concerned, remain unchanged during the derivation and emerge in a sequence (this is why I have assigned indices to them), some of them being

$$
\begin{array}{}
p_0 = 1\\
p_1 = C_1\\
p_2 = C_1^2 - C_2\\
p_3 = C_1^3 - 2C_1C_2\\
p_4 = C_1^4 - 3C_1^2 C_2 + C_2^2\\
p_5 = C_1^5 - 4C_1^3 C_2 + 3C_1 C_2^2
\end{array}
$$

Bear in mind that I have deduced these formulæ by deriving the equations for $\alpha_i$ starting from the last equation of the system. Doing some algebra in order to “feel” this is advised. I should be exceedingly grateful to those who at least give me a meaningful hint. As for me, several days of tears and 3 sacrifices to Satan have not yet brought any success in this regard.

Comment: Why not represent a polynomial as an ($n+1$)-dimensional column vector of its coefficients? Then a single derivative acting on a polynomial becomes a matrix (lets call it $D$) which is all zeroes except for 1, 2, 3... just above the main diagonal. Two derivatives is the square of that matrix, and so on. Then this becomes a linear algebra problem which is solved by inverting the matrix $M = c_0 I  + c_1 D + c_2 D^2$: $F = M^{-1}P$

Comment: One way to solve it is to differentiate the identity $1, 2, \dots, n$ times and set $x=0$. You get a linear system of $n+1$ equations to solve for $F(0), F'(0), \dots F^{(n)}(0)$, then $\alpha_k = F^{(k)}(0) / k!$.